# Camera changing after rendering

Tags: rendering, camera

Before rendering everything works fine, i have my camera on scene at my desired spot. But when i try to render it looks like my camera is inside a mesh. After that when i look at the scene properties my default camera changed to "door" (one of my models). How is that possible? "Door" don't even have camera attached, there is only 1 camera on my scene. How i can fix that?

I provided some screenshots to make my problem more clear to you:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpLhm.jpg

Comment: please include screenshots next time just by pasting in your question. So users don't have to click on your external links. And please write a short sentence about your experience (e.g. i am a bloody beginner) because otherwise people might think you are an experienced user and then the answer will be very short (and experienced users will know what to do) but you wouldn't understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the "Scene properties"-tab. The icon looks like this: [image]

[image]

Here you can see the scene properties.

If you want to see the "Object properties" [image]

just press the right icon.